# Testing whether an abstract object is an instance of one of the several concrete classes

Tags: c#, object-oriented, casting

I have an abstract object and I need to test whether it is an instance of one of the several concrete classes. Every concrete class has a `Value` property that is not inherited.

The following points need to be true:

- Single cast per class
- Short circuit when one test is successful
- No unnecessary casts

This is the solution I came up with:

```
public string Value { get; set; }
```

code in the setter of `ObserverDto`:

```
_observerDto = value; // underlying field
var oldValue = Value;

// single cast before test, goto to emulate if - else if
var booleanObserverDto = ObserverDto as BooleanObserverDto;
if (booleanObserverDto != null)
{
    Value = booleanObserverDto.CurrentValue == true ? booleanObserverDto.TrueText :
            booleanObserverDto.CurrentValue == false ? booleanObserverDto.FalseText : booleanObserverDto.CurrentValue.ToString();
    goto castDone;
}

var intObserverDto = ObserverDto as IntObserverDto;
if (intObserverDto != null)
{
    Value = intObserverDto.CurrentValue.ToString();
    goto castDone;
}

var decimalObserverDto = ObserverDto as DecimalObserverDto;
if (decimalObserverDto != null)
{
    Value = Convert.ToSingle(decimalObserverDto.CurrentValue).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    goto castDone;
}

var stringObserverDto = ObserverDto as StringObserverDto;
if (stringObserverDto != null)
    Value = stringObserverDto.CurrentValue;

castDone:;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
    Value = "NULL";

if(!Value.Equals(oldValue))
    UpdateObserver(Name, Value);
```

I don't know of any possibility to have a statement between `if` and `else if`, but it might be better than using `goto`. Is there any way I could do a cast before an `else if`?

I can't change anything about the class structure or make it more generic because these classes are from a library I need to use.

Comment: Ugh labels... the whole casting code is pretty duplicate, make a TryCast method for that and it will look so much cleaner. Without labels.

Comment: It's not just the setter, the whole design is odd with its `Value = "NULL"` and all those observers. You're doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @t3chb0t I mentioned it being a setter, in case anyone was wondering what `value` was (it's a keyword). The application being developed shows 'observers' and their values, it is totally unrelated to the observer pattern.

Comment: Obviously we don't expect you to post the whole project, but this code could use some more context. I'm guessing, for example, that `ObserverDto` is a property whose getter returns `_observerDto`, and that `Value` is a property something like `public string Value { get; private set; }`, but without definite confirmation of those (and maybe other similar) points it's senseless to review this code because we can't tell what impact suggested refactors would have on correctness.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You are right, I did not think of that. I editted the question.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have a good reason for not having an overriden `GetValue()` method on each sub-class, an extension method for each class, say, `GetValue()` should solve it.

```
public static class ObserverExtensions
{
  private static readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<ObserverDto, string>> _lookup = new Dictionary<Type, Func<ObserverDto, string>>
  {
     {typeof(BooleanObserverDto), dto => ((BooleanObserverDto)dto).GetValue() },
     {typeof(IntObserverDto), dto => ((IntObserverDto)dto).GetValue() },
     {typeof(DecimalObserverDto), dto => ((DecimalObserverDto)dto).GetValue() },
     {typeof(StringObserverDto), dto => ((StringObserverDto)dto).GetValue() },
  };

  public static string GetValue(this ObserverDto observerDto)
  {
       return _lookup[observerDto.GetType()](observerDto);
  }

  public static string GetValue(this BooleanObserverDto booleanObserverDto)
  {
     return booleanObserverDto.CurrentValue == true ? booleanObserverDto.TrueText :
            booleanObserverDto.CurrentValue == false ? booleanObserverDto.FalseText : booleanObserverDto.CurrentValue.ToString();
  }

  public static string GetValue(this IntObserverDto intObserverDto)
  {
     return intObserverDto.CurrentValue.ToString();
  }

  public static string GetValue(this DecimalObserverDto decimalObserverDto)
  {
     return Convert.ToSingle(decimalObserverDto.CurrentValue).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
  }

  public static string GetValue(this StringObserverDto stringObserverDto)
  {
     return stringObserverDto.CurrentValue;
  }
}


//...
Value = ObserverDto.GetValue();
```

One nice thing about this solution  is that we can add more classes (say, `DateTimeObserverDto`) without having to open up the set/update code. We simply add another extension method.

**Edit: Correction**

The extension methods only work if the references to the objects are of the concrete type. It doesn't work when passing in `ObserverDto` objects

```
// Passed
[TestMethod]
public void CheckConversions()
{
     var a = new IntObserverDto { CurrentValue = 17 };
     var b = new DecimalObserverDto { CurrentValue = 19.1m };
     var c = new BooleanObserverDto { CurrentValue = false };
     var d = new StringObserverDto { CurrentValue = "Hello World" };

     Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", d.GetValue());
     Assert.AreEqual("False", c.GetValue());
     Assert.AreEqual("19.1", b.GetValue());
     Assert.AreEqual("17", a.GetValue());
}

// Fails (doesn't compile) - no GetValue() for ObserverDto
[TestMethod]
public void CheckConversions()
{
     ObserverDto a = new IntObserverDto { CurrentValue = 17 };

     Assert.AreEqual("17", a.GetValue());
}
```

Best I can think of (sans adding a virtual method to `ObserverDto`) is use a lookup in the extension method (see above)

Comment: sorry about the last comment, though I had over written it but timed out and couldn't be edited :( . You are correct. In the test code I used, everything was var typed and I ended up with the concrete types and the extensions found the correct one. If passing in an ObserverDto, the correct GetValue() not found. Updated